# how to compare list of functions from 2 files?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I wanted to list all functions in 2 files I have, so I used:

```
cat <file_A> | grep -E "^function"
cat <file_B> | grep -E "^function"
```

How can I compare the outputs and highlight the similarities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options here:

- if you need GUI solution - then you can use [Meld Merge tool](http://meldmerge.org/):

  ```
  sudo apt install meld

  meld <(grep -E "^function" file_A) <(grep -E "^function" file_B)
  ```
- if you need terminal solution - use power of diff:

  ```
  diff <(grep -E "^function" file_A) <(grep -E "^function" file_B)
  ```

Comment: no way of doing so without saving output to files?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [process substitution](https://superuser.com/a/1060002/664884) functionality in this way:

```
diff <(cat <file_A> | grep -E "^function") <(cat <file_B> | grep -E "^function")
```

You do not need to use `cat` in this case. Also, there is a nice wrapper of `diff` called `colordiff` (it must be installed: `sudo apt install colordiff`). Here is one of my favorite usages:

```
colordiff --side-by-side --left-column --width=180 --show-C-function <(grep -E "^function" <file_A>) <(grep -E "^function" <file_B>)
```